# What does one call a joke which contains another relative joke?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How is this type of joke called?

> There are two hard things in computer science:
>   cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

> There are only two hard problems in distributed systems:
>   2. Exactly-once delivery 1. Guaranteed order of messages 2. Exactly-once delivery

I call it joke-in-joke, but how do linguists call it?

Comment: I would say neither is a _joke-in-a-joke_. In the first, the joke _is_ that the length of the list is "off by one" from what was announced. The second is essentially the same, although there are two _components_ to the joke (the order's wrong, and the "exactly-once" message appears twice). Along somewhat similar lines: "_There are 10 types of people in the world. Those that understand binary and those that don't_".

Comment: I'm not a linguistics expert, but given the subject matter, I guess linguists would probably still call it a *joke*. Entertainers, on the other hand, might have more specialised terms for it.

Comment: You could call them autological or self-demonstrating jokes.

Comment: @lawrence: looking at the migration history, it looks like linguists called it *off topic*!

Comment: Linguists have only a primitive understanding of jokes, as can be seen by [what passes for humor among linguists](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/daysinmay.html).

Comment: Obviously, if it's a relative joke it's *inherited*!

Comment: I'd say neither are jokes! Is this as funny as they get in computer science...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn’t a joke-within-a-joke, as there’s only one. It’s an example of **self-reference**.

[From the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy:](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/)
*In the context of language, self-reference is used to denote a statement that refers to itself or its own referent. The most famous example of a self-referential sentence is the liar sentence: “This sentence is not true.”*

There’s a [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-referential_humor) for **self-referential humour**:
*Self-referential humor or self-reflexive humor is a type of comedic expressionthat—either directed toward some other subject, or openly directed toward itself—intentionally alludes to the very person who is expressing the humor in a comedic fashion, or to some specific aspect of that same comedic expression.*

Searching “self-referential humour” or “self-referential joke” finds many examples, e.g. [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-self-referential-joke-ever) 
and [here](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~jim/selfref.html):

*Repeat after me, "I will think for myself."*

*Condemn ambiguity and other stuff.*

*The technical term for "being unable to remember the word you want" is ...erm...*

*I never make predictions. I never have and I never will.*

*I went to a bookstore and asked the saleswoman, “Where's the self-help section?” She said if she told me, it would defeat the purpose.*

And my favourite: *"Give credit where credit is due." –Unknown*

The common factor seems to be that the statement or anecdote is funny because it refers to itself, or one of its elements, in a way that defeats its face-value meaning or purpose.

For some reason, it appeals especially to computer scientists/professionals and mathematicians.